# Prove by contradiction : if $n-m$ is odd , then $n^2-m^2$ is odd AND Prove by contradiction that if $A \subseteq B$, then $A-B= \varnothing$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm just checking on my work, I feel something is missing.

### 1-Prove by contradiction : if $n-m$ is odd , then $n^2-m^2$ is odd .

since n-m is odd, then $ n=2k+1$ and $m=2t+1 $
assume $ n^2-m^2 $ is even then,
$(2k+1)^2-(2t+1)^2=(4k^2+4k+1)-(4t^2+4t+1)=4(k^2+1)+1-4(t^2+1)+1 $, which is odd
it's contrary to our assumption that $  n^2-m^2 $ is even
$\therefore  n^2-m^2$ must be odd

### 2-Prove by contradiction that if $A \subseteq B$, then $A-B= \varnothing$

1-Assume $ A\subseteq B.$ By contradiction, suppose $ A - B \ne \varnothing.$
$\therefore \forall x \in A - B \therefore x \in A$ and $ x \notin B$ a contradiction.
As a result, $ A - B = \varnothing.$
2- Assume $A - B = \varnothing$. By contradiction, suppose $A \nsubseteq B$\
$\therefore \forall x \in A$ such that $x \notin B$.
$\therefore$ $x \in A - B$  a contradiction.
As a result, $A \subseteq B$.
$\therefore$ if $ A \subseteq B$ then $A - B = \varnothing$.

Comment: The hypothesis in the first question states that $n - m$ is odd, not that $n$ and $m$ are both odd (which would imply $n - m$ is even).

Comment: One question per post is good practice. In this case, they're from separate topics entirely.

Comment: It seems that 2) is an **iff**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2-Prove by contradiction that if $A\subset B$ , then $A\setminus
>  B=\emptyset$

Proof: Assume the contrary, that$A\setminus
 B\neq \emptyset$

Then, $\exists\text{ at least one element } x\in A\setminus
 B$.

$x\in A\setminus B\implies x \in A \text{ but } x\notin B$.

And it contradict that $A\subset B$